# confused about largest diameter of binary tree problem

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree, depth-first-search

Not sure how this works...

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left, self.right = left, right

  def find_diameter(self, root):
    self.calculate_height(root)
    return self.treeDiameter

  def calculate_height(self, currentNode):
    if currentNode is None:
      return 0

    leftTreeDiameter = self.calculate_height(currentNode.left)
    rightTreeDiameter = self.calculate_height(currentNode.right)

    diameter = leftTreeDiameter + rightTreeDiameter + 1
    self.treeDiameter = max(self.treeDiameter, diameter)

    return max(leftTreeDiameter, rightTreeDiameter) + 1
```

The above code works to get the max diameter of a binary tree but I don't understand the last line in `calculate_height`. Why do we need to return `max(leftTreeDiameter, rightTreeDiameter) + 1`

I obviously don't understand it but what I do know is that for each `currentNode` we are going to keep going down the left side of the tree and similarly then do the same for the right. If we ended up with no node (meaning right before we were at a leaf node) then we return 0 as we don't want to add 1 for a node that does not exist.

The only place that seems to be adding anything besides 0 is the last line of code in `calculate_height` because although we are adding `leftTreeDiameter + rightTreeDiameter + 1` to get the total diameter this is only possible because of the `return 0` and `return max(leftTreeDiameter, rightTreeDiameter) + 1` correct?

Also, I am confused as to why leftTreeDiameter can be assigned `self.calculate_height(currentNode.left)`. What I mean is that I thought I would need something like...

```
def calculate_left_height(self, currentNode, height=0):
  if currentNode is None:
    return 0

  self.calculate_height(currentNode.left, height + 1)
  
  return height
```

where we just add 1 to the height each time. In this case instead of doing something like `leftTreeDiameter += self.calculate_height(currentNode.left)` I just pass in as an argument `height + 1` each time we see a node.

but if I do this I would need a separate method just to calculate the right height as well and in my `find_diameter` method would need to recursively call `find_diameter` with both `root.left` and also with `root.right`.

Where is my logic wrong and how is it that `calculate_height` actually works. I guess I am having trouble trying to figure out how to keep track of the stack?

Comment: What is the "diameter" of a tree?

Comment: not sure if I can explain it well but at the parent node if you go to the left child and then from that child go to the left and left and so on and do the same from the parent node but to the right count each time you see a node and add 1 for the parent node. This is what the diameter is for this question. If there is a sub-tree with a greater diameter than that diameter is the one considered. Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe a link to the problem would be best...

Comment: Sorry its a course online that is paid for so I can't simply provide a link but I think @trincot has cleared it up for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names used in this code are confusing: `leftTreeDiameter` and `rightTreeDiameter` are not diameters, but heights.

Secondly, the function `calculate_height` has side effects, which is not very nice. On the one hand it *returns* a height, and simultaneously it *assigns* a diameter. This is confusing. Many Python coders would prefer a function to be pure and just *return* something, without altering anything else. Or, alternatively, a function could only alter some state and *not* return it. Doing both can be confusing.

Also, it is confusing that although the class is called `TreeNode`, its `find_diameter` method still requires a node as argument. This is counter-intuitive. We would expect the method to take `self` as the node to act on, not the argument.

But let's just rename the variables and add some comments:

```
leftHeight = self.calculate_height(currentNode.left)
rightHeight = self.calculate_height(currentNode.right)

# What is the size of the longest path from leaf-to-leaf 
#   whose top node is the current node?
diameter = leftHeight + rightHeight + 1
# Is this path longer than the longest path that we
#   had found so far? If so, take this one.
self.treeDiameter = max(self.treeDiameter, diameter)
# The height of the tree rooted at the current node
#   is the height of the highest childtree (either left or right), 
#   with one added to account for the current node
return max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1
```

It should be clear, but do realise that `self` in this process is always the instance on which the `find_diameter` method is called, and does not really play a role as actual node, as the root is passed as argument. So the repeated assignment to `self.treeDiameter` is always to the same *one* property. This property is not created on every node... just on the node on which you invoke `find_diameter`.

I hope the inserted comments have clarified how this algorithm works.

NB: your own idea on creating `calculate_left_height` is not going to do it: it never alters the value of `height` that it receives as argument, and ends up returning it. So it returns the same value it already receives. That is obviously not going to do much...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and for the advice. I do not understand why we need to get the height of the tree rooted at the current node. For instance I only care what the height of the tree is from left and also from right rooted at the current node is. I know that with the height we can get the height of the left and right but why are we taking max? If I take the height of the left side and height of the right side then I just care about adding those together the max is throwing me off?

Comment: You should look at it in a "bottom-up" way. So start at the deepest recursion level, where the height is 0. Then you backtrack, ...and backtrack. So you always know the height of the children before determining the height of the node itself. Now what is the height of a (tree at a) node? If it has a short subtree at its left, and a high subtree at its right, then surely the height of the left subtree has become irrelevant. The total height is then completely determined by the right side. Hence: max.

Comment: Don't confuse the returned *height* with the calculation of the *diameter*. I only discuss *height* in my previous comment. Don't mix those two up. I warned for that mixup in my answer. Indeed, you do not need `max` in the calculation of the *diameter*. But you *do*, when you need to calculate the *height* when you only know the heights of the children.

Comment: When the height of the root's left subtree is 2, and of the right subtree is 1, then the *height* (!!!) of the root is *not* determined by the right subtree, only by the left subtree. The height of the root is 2+1=3 (not 4). Another thing is the *diameter*. For that the calculation is different. It adds up the heights and adds 1 for the root itself: 2+1+1=4. There both heights are important, they are added. Please do realise that the calculations for *height* and *diameter* are completely different. Don't mix them up.

Comment: Yes, I do know they are but I think what I had wrong was this. Please correct me if I am still wrong. We go left and keep going left we get the height and once we are done we go right because of `self.calculate_height(currentNode.right)` and right after we keep going left and this is how we take care of subtrees and we always keep the max because anything less than the max height becomes irrelevant as you mentioned.

Comment: So if we had a tree with the left side having many subtrees we only consider the one with greatest height and similarly to the right side of the tree while also considering the tree itself starting from the root node having a height as well

Comment: Yes, although it is less messy if you use *induction*: assume that the recursive call returns the correct result for the two children. Then see how that means the height is also correctly calculated for the current node and returned. So, ... if the base case is calculated correctly (and it is: 0 is the correct height for a leaf node), then by induction all other heights are calculated correctly too.